# Unable to define table explicitly

Tags: sql-server

I was sent some code and I am trying to adapt it to join an additional table.

The new table shares column names and so I need to make the existing code explicit using **"rt."**.

However, the higher level nesting will not support that, and I keep getting the error: **The multi-part identifier could not be bound**

```
    SELECT temp2.AOV AS "AOV",
       temp2.num_projects AS "#Projects",
       temp2.GMV as GMV,
       (temp2.revenue - LAG(temp2.revenue, 1) 
       OVER(ORDER BY temp2.time_range)) / LAG(temp2.revenue, 1) 
       OVER(ORDER BY temp2.time_range) AS "M-o-M Rev%",
       temp2.time_range AS "Time Range"
    FROM 
      (SELECT avg(rt.incentive + rt.fee) AS AOV,
          sum(rt.fee) as Revenue,
           count(distinct rt.projectId) AS num_projects,
          time_range
    FROM
     ( SELECT sum(rt.fee) AS fee,
            sum(rt.incentive) AS incentive,
              projectId,
              DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,rt.createdAt),0) AS time_range
      FROM dbo.transactions AS rt
      GROUP BY DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,rt.createdAt),0),
               projectId ) AS temp
   GROUP BY temp.time_range ) AS temp2
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `rt` outside the scope as well, where you should be using `temp`, this might work for you:

```
SELECT temp2.AOV AS "AOV",
   temp2.num_projects AS "#Projects",
   temp2.GMV as GMV,
   (temp2.revenue - LAG(temp2.revenue, 1) 
   OVER(ORDER BY temp2.time_range)) / LAG(temp2.revenue, 1) 
   OVER(ORDER BY temp2.time_range) AS "M-o-M Rev%",
   temp2.time_range AS "Time Range"
FROM 
  (SELECT avg(temp.incentive + temp.fee) AS AOV,
      sum(temp.fee) as Revenue,
       count(distinct temp.projectId) AS num_projects,
      time_range
   FROM
      ( SELECT sum(rt.fee) AS fee,
        sum(rt.incentive) AS incentive,
        projectId,
        DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,rt.createdAt),0) AS time_range
        FROM dbo.transactions AS rt
        GROUP BY DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,rt.createdAt),0),
  projectId ) AS temp
```

as `rt` is the innermost level and an outer layer in your query names that result as the `temp` relation, so you should use that in the outer `select`.